# How can I get my handler to call a runnable in microseconds rather than milliseconds?

Tags: java, android, handler

How can I get my handler to call a runnable in microseconds rather than milliseconds?

I have a runnable called 'pollTask' that my handler calls upon every 1 millisecond. However, I would like to know what methods I could use to get the handler to call the 'pollTask' runnable every x microseconds? I understand this will likely require completely different methods but am open to any suggestions. Thanks

```
myHandler.postDelayed(pollTask, 1);
```

Comment: You should explain a little about why you need this task to execute so often. Android is not an [RTOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_operating_system), and any `delayMillis` you specify to `postDelayed()` is simply a minimum interval, not a guarantee of execution during any particular clock tick.

Comment: I am trying to read the max amplitude from the microphone manually (using APIs that can do this at 44.1KHz write to a file)

Comment: This approach sounds questionable. Usually, when computers have to deliver data at higher (relative) rates, a device driver will batch a large number of measurements into a single buffer, rather than requiring the CPU to poll at a high rate. (Hint: [AudioRecord](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioRecord) is a built-in feature of the OS, and it can solve this problem much more elegantly.)

Answer (score 0):

You simply can't. However, you can use [java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html) api to easily convert from nanoseconds to milliseconds.